# Export Wordpress Page Template To HTML & Download?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I currently have a custom post type and I would like the option to export the page template into html which would then download the html file?

I have seen this done before, please see screenshot below.

[image: Screen Shot 2016-11-02 at 11.47.04.png]

Can anybody please point me in the right direction? All my searched seem to be for making a whole wordpress site static which is not what I need?

Answer (score 0):

If the server has `wget` on it, use that via ``exec()`, etc. in a custom plugin. Pass it the URL of the preview or autosave along with copies of any cookies from the admin area request. Be sure to use`escapeshellarg()` You can limit wget to a single page + assets with the right arguments, study the man page for it.